# Шаблон Producer Consumer. Не всегда проходит тест

Tags: java, многопоточность, junit, декоратор

Вот сам код:

```
import net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy;
import net.jcip.annotations.ThreadSafe;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * Класс состоит их двух методов:
 * Первый добавляет элементы в коллекцию если очередь не полна.
 * Второй извлекает элементы из коллекции если очередь не полна.
 */
@ThreadSafe
public class SimpleBlockingQueue<E> {

    @GuardedBy("this")
    private Queue<E> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    @GuardedBy("this")
    private E size;

    public SimpleBlockingQueue(E size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public synchronized void offer(E value) {
        if (queue.size() > (int) size) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Исключения типа InterruptedException перехвачено");
            }
        } else {
            queue.offer(value);
            notify();
        }
    }

    public synchronized E poll() {
        E result = null;
        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Исключения типа InterruptedException перехвачено");
            }
        } else {
            result = queue.poll();
            notify();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public synchronized int getSizeQueue() {
        return queue.size();
    }
}
```

Вот код теста:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class SimpleBlockingQueueTest {
    SimpleBlockingQueue<Integer> blocking = new SimpleBlockingQueue<>(7);
    private Thread producer;
    private Thread consumer;

    @Before
    public void when() {
        producer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 6) {
                    blocking.offer(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };

        consumer = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 6) {
                    assertThat(blocking.getSizeQueue(), is(6 - i));
                    assertThat(blocking.poll(), is(i));
                    assertThat(blocking.getSizeQueue(), is(6 - 1 - i));
                    i++;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();
        producer.join();
        consumer.join();
    }
}
```

Иногда проходит тест, а иногда бывают ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: Скорее всего это из-за потоков.

Comment: Вы должны "вбить себе в голову", что поведение многопоточной программы **не определено!** Нет **никакой гарантии**, что последовательность выполнения потоков будет следующей: producer, consumer, producer, consumer и т.д. Последовательность может быть и такой: producer, producer, consumer, consumer и т.д.

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <6>
     but: was <0>
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
 at ru.job4j.blocking.SimpleBlockingQueueTest$2.run(SimpleBlockingQueueTest.java:32)

Comment: @AlexandarVysotskiy Исправить вопрос, можно с помощью кнопки «[править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/876362/edit)» под ним

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему тест проверяет только, что элементы были добавлены в нужном порядке.

Проблема связана с тем, что нет гарантии, что `producer` выполнится раньше `consumer`. В запусках, которые не проходят, `consumer` выполняется первым и не обнаруживает элементов в очереди.

Чтобы исправить можете сначала дождаться пока `producer` завершит работу:

```
producer.start();
producer.join();
//и после запускаем consumer
consumer.start();
consumer.join();
```

Насколько это решение допустимо зависит от поставленной перед тестом задачи. Если просто нужно протестировать порядок элементов в очереди, то этот вариант подойдет, но в этом случае можно обойтись и без потоков. Если же нужно протестировать параллельную работу, то этот вариант не подойдет, нужно будет либо настраивать синхронизацию потоков, либо строить логику получения значения чтобы `consumer` дожидался следующего значения, перед тем как его сверять.